# How to load (and access to configure) a GoogleMap into a <fragment> within a Layout Fragment Derived from MvxFragment in MvvmCross

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm new to MvvmCross, Xamarin and Android development and as such the basis for my development is a modified version of [XPlatformMenus MvvmCross Sample Project](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/XPlatformMenus)

Try as I might I cannot successfully set up a google map for addition of simple positional markers (ie. for want of expert wording, getting access to the "GoogleMap" instance so I can Add "MapMarker" instances to it and possibly configure some map options to give it my desired behaviours).

Before attempting to access the google map and inject markers my layout fragment "fragment_asset_details" (or Asset Details View in my case) was successfully displaying an Android Google Map (full page view).

With reference to my included code snippets, the "FindFragmentById" call returns a "null" frag value every time. In debugging I see the SupportFragment Manager knows of the Layout fragments, but the GoogleMap fragment is absent entirely.

Some general (and directly related) Questions are:

1. Is there an example of MvxFragment related GoogleMap "nesting", that
   I have missed ?
2. Do I have to programmatically add the GoogleMap fragment to the fragment container in a similar fashion to [Getting
   a Reference to a GoogleMap in a fragment using Support Library
   v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677989/getting-a-reference-to-a-googlemap-in-a-fragment-using-support-library-v4) ?
3. Have I chosen the right point in the lifecycle of the container fragment to successfully acheive my desired outcome ?

I will be happy to add any details requested, this post (initially) has been limited to those elements of my prototype that I feel most likely relate to the problem I'm facing.

The packages Config for my Application (to indicate in particular the subject version of MvvmCross):

```
    <packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="modernhttpclient" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Binding" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Core" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Droid.Shared" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Platform" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Plugin.Json" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.Plugin.Visibility" version="4.2.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="29.0.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="29.0.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" version="29.0.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
</packages>
```

The layout for the MvxFragment "fragment_asset_details.axml" is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/asset_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

I have defined a Fragment "AssetDetailsFragment" as follows:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using MyApp.Core.ViewModels.Base;
using MyApp.Core.ViewModels.Assets;
using MyApp.Droid.Utilities;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Shared.Attributes;

namespace MyApp.Droid.Fragments
{
    [MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]
    [Register("myapp.droid.fragments.AssetDetailsFragment")]
    public class AssetDetailsFragment : BaseFragment<AssetDetailsViewModel>
    {
        private Marker _assetMarker;

        private GoogleMap _asset_map;

        public bool SetUpGoogleMap(int resourceId)
        {
            if (null != _loco_map) return false;

            if (FragmentManager != null)
            {
                var frag = (SupportMapFragment) base.Activity.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(resourceId);
                var mapReadyCallback = new OnMapReadyClass();

                mapReadyCallback.MapReadyAction += delegate (GoogleMap googleMap)
                {
                    _asset_map = googleMap;
                };

                if (frag != null) frag.GetMapAsync(mapReadyCallback);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (SetUpGoogleMap(Resource.Id.asset_map))
            {
                var viewModel = (AssetDetailsViewModel)ViewModel;
                var options = new MarkerOptions();
                options.SetPosition(new LatLng(viewModel.AssetDetails.latitude,
                    viewModel.AssetDetails.longitude));
                options.SetTitle(viewModel.Asset.name);
                _assetMarker = _asset_map.AddMarker(options);
            }
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            ShowHamburgerMenu = true;
            var result =  base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            return result;
        }

        protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.fragment_asset_details;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading it via Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

In your Fragment's OnCreateView method:

```
var supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance();
var supportMapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);

var ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
ft.Add(Resource.Id.map_frame, supportMapFragment, typeof(SupportMapFragment).Name);
ft.Commit();
```

You will need to implement the `IOnMapReadyCallback` on your Fragment which will provide the `GetMapAsync(..)` method.